# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'free_symbols'

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in python. I'm not able to understand what the problem is?

```
  from sympy.solvers import solve
  from sympy import Symbol
  import colorama
  x = Symbol('x')
  time.sleep(1)
  print("\n")
  print(Fore.GREEN + "Welcome to the Algebraic calculator, please input an equation.")
  print("\n")
  algebra1 = input(Fore.WHITE + "[>] ")
  print(solve(algebra1))
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
print(solve(algebra1))
File "/home/runner/SuperCalculator/venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py", line 867, in solve
symbols = set().union(*[fi.free_symbols for fi in f])
File "/home/runner/SuperCalculator/venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py", line 867, in <listcomp>
symbols = set().union(*[fi.free_symbols for fi in f])
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'free_symbols'
```